# MySQL - How to filter and show max value from a group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the following query that will give me sales figures from all the stores in my database:

```
SELECT s.shopname AS "Store",
       e.empname AS "Employee",
       e1.empname AS "Manager",
       SUM(p.amount) AS "Total Sales"
FROM fss_Shop s
       JOIN fss_Employee e ON e.shopid = s.shopid
       JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = e.empnin
       JOIN fss_Employee e1 ON e1.empnin = e.mgrnin
GROUP BY e.empname, e.shopid
```

The query executes and returns data. It should give me the top salesperson from each store, alongside other data as you can see from the query.

The problem I am having with it is that for some stores it returns more than one employee where there "Total Sales" is clearly different. For example, for STORE A it will return John (Sales Value = £1000) as well as Martin (Sales Value = £2000). I expect it to only return the employee with the highest sales value.

How can I change the query so that it returns the employees with only the highest sales value per store?

The link below will give you an idea of what the tables look like:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t94XmTEMgXpmSLS3e8HWAh/1

Comment: Does the query really run okay as it's written? You are putting e.shopid in the the `GROUP BY` but it doesn't appear anywhere in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Where in your query does it specify that you only want the maximum value returned?  Is one of the tables supposed to have the saleperson with the most sales already?

Comment: @PatJones Yes it runs i just tested it now

Comment: Do you have the schema for fss_Payments?

Comment: @PatJones Yep just updated it. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t94XmTEMgXpmSLS3e8HWAh/1

Comment: @HoldTight it is not possible to run it on mysql without errors

Comment: Thanks, I see it now...will post another possible answer in a few!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `HAVING` and `ALL`

```
SELECT s.shopname AS "Store",
   e.empname AS "Employee",
   e1.empname AS "Manager",
   SUM(p.amount) AS "Total Sales"
FROM fss_Shop s
   JOIN fss_Employee e ON e.shopid = s.shopid
   JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = e.empnin
   JOIN fss_Employee e1 ON e1.empnin = e.mgrnin
GROUP BY e.empname, s.shopid
HAVING SUM(p.amount) >= ALL(
   SELECT SUM(p.amount)
   FROM fss_Employee e
   JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = e.empnin
   WHERE e.shopid = s.shopid
   GROUP BY e.empname
)
```

if `ALL` doesn't work for you. You may change it like this

```
SELECT s.shopname AS "Store",
   e.empname AS "Employee",
   e1.empname AS "Manager",
   SUM(p.amount) AS "Total Sales"
FROM fss_Shop s
   JOIN fss_Employee e ON e.shopid = s.shopid
   JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = e.empnin
   JOIN fss_Employee e1 ON e1.empnin = e.mgrnin
GROUP BY e.empname, e.shopid
HAVING SUM(p.amount) = (
   SELECT MAX(t.samount)
   FROM
   (
     SELECT SUM(p.amount) samount
     FROM fss_Employee emp
     JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = emp.empnin
     WHERE emp.shopid = e.shopid
     GROUP BY emp.empname
   ) t
)
```

ok and the next version that avoids correlated subquery behind `FROM`

```
SELECT s.shopname AS "Store",
   e.empname AS "Employee",
   e1.empname AS "Manager",
   SUM(p.amount) AS "Total Sales"
FROM fss_Shop s
   JOIN fss_Employee e ON e.shopid = s.shopid
   JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = e.empnin
   JOIN fss_Employee e1 ON e1.empnin = e.mgrnin
GROUP BY e.empnin, e.shopid
HAVING (e.shopid, SUM(p.amount)) IN
(
  SELECT t.shopid, MAX(t.samount)
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT emp.shopid, SUM(p.amount) samount
     FROM fss_Employee emp
     JOIN fss_Payment p ON p.empnin = emp.empnin
     GROUP BY emp.empname, emp.shopid
  ) t
  GROUP BY t.shopid
)
```

Comment: Getting syntax error around the `HAVING` `'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 10`

Comment: I have no LIMIT in query

Comment: It says 2 errors were found `Unrecognized keyword. (near "ALL" at position 337)`
`Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 340)`

Comment: Removing `ALL` removes the syntax errors but then MySQL gives another error saying `SUBQUERY RETURNS MORE THAN ONE ROW`

Comment: @HoldTight try the second version

Comment: Getting `unknown column s.shopid in WHERE clause` when using your updated version.

Comment: @HoldTight man, it is really strange. I have updated the aliases. Can you try now?

Comment: @Holdtight ok and the last version? Unfortunately, I get errors when running your create table script, so I'm unable to test it ...